# ggplot2: adding both a size legend and a colour legend: only one appears automatically

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

Dataset (originalRfiltered3):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fekw0o7ybdilnpr/originalRfiltered3.xlsx?dl=0

or dput output here: http://txt.do/15k69

I am trying to plot the following plot

[image: Correlation between size of parasite and size of host]

To achieve this i did the following:

```
ggplot(originalRfiltered3, aes(x = host.length, y = of.thorax) ) + 
 geom_point(aes(size = originalRfiltered3$number.simp), col = "black") + 
 geom_point(aes(col = host.sex), size = originalRfiltered3$number.simp) + 
 stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "black", formula = y~poly(x,2)) + 
 scale_colour_manual(name = "Host Sex", 
   values = c("red","blue"), labels=c("F","M")) + 
 scale_size_continuous(name = "Group Size",
   labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4+") ) + 
 theme_classic() + 
 labs(x = "Host length (cm)" ) +
 labs(y = "Parasite length (mm)" ) +
 labs(title = "Correlation between size of host and parasite")
```

I know I can specify both size and colour in the same aes line, but this only generates one of the legends. <-- if you can help me here then my problem is solved.

I would like to produce what is in the picture attached, but without having to plot two sets of points, which results in the black underlying point (so that the legend is automatically generated) and the second layer of coloured points (so that the colour legend is generated).

I tried generating the underlying size points with white colour, which gives me the right visual look in the plot with a white background, but then makes the differently sized circles in the legend white, which is not what i want.

I also tried scale_size_manual and adding the points, but i get an error message that because size is a continuous variable, it wont work.

> dput(originalRfiltered3)
> structure(list(infection.cluster = c("B12_ES079_A", "B12_ES079_A",
> "B12_ES080_A", "B12_ES080_A", "B12_ES081_A", "B12_ES081_A", "B12_ES083_A",
> "B12_ES083_A", "B12_ES084_A", "B12_ES084_A", "B12_ES086_A", "B12_ES086_A",
> "B13_ES029_A", "B13_ES029_A", "B13_ES029_B", "B13_ES029_B", "B13_ES039_A",
> "B13_ES039_A", "B13_ES039_A", "B13_ES076_A", "B13_ES076_A", "B13_ES076_A",
> "B13_ES076_A", "B13_ES076_A", "B13_ES076_A", "B13_ES081_A", "B13_ES081_A",
> "B13_ES086_A", "B13_ES086_A", "B13_ES086_A", "B13_ES096_A", "B13_ES096_A",
> "B13_ES101_A", "B13_ES101_A", "B13_ES121_A", "B13_ES121_A", "B19_ES007_A",
> "B19_ES016_A", "B19_ES016_A", "B19_ES016_B", "B19_ES016_B", "B19_ES016_B",
> "B19_ES016_B", "B19_ES016_B", "B19_ES016_C", "B19_ES026_A", "B19_ES048_A",
> "B19_ES048_A", "B19_ES40_A", "B19_ES40_A", "B21_ES001_A", "B21_ES001_A",
> "B21_ES002_A", "B21_ES002_A", "B21_ES003_A", "B21_ES003_A", "B21_ES004_A",
> "B21_ES004_A", "B21_ES005_A", "B21_ES005_A", "B21_ES006_A", "B21_ES006_A",
> "B21_ES007_A", "B21_ES007_A", "B21_ES008_A", "B21_ES008_A", "B21_ES009_A",
> "B21_ES009_A", "B21_ES011_A", "B21_ES011_A", "B21_ES011_A", "B21_ES012_A",
> "B21_ES012_A", "B21_ES012_A", "B21_ES012_A", "B21_ES012_A", "B21_ES012_A",
> "B21_ES013_A", "B21_ES013_A", "B21_ES013_A", "B21_ES014_A", "B22_ES1074_A",
> "B22_ES1074_A", "B22_ES1074_A", "B22_ES1075_A", "B22_ES1075_A",
> "B22_ES1075_A", "B22_ES1075_A", "B22_ES1075_A", "B22_ES1075_A",
> "B22_ES1075_A", "B22_ES1130_A", "B22_ES1130_B", "B22_ES1132_A",
> "B22_ES1134_A", "B22_ES1134_A", "B22_ES1137_A", "B22_ES1137_A",
> "B22_ES1138_A", "B22_ES1138_A", "B22_ES1138_A", "B22_ES1138_A",
> "B22_ES1139_A", "B22_ES1139_A", "B22_ES1140_A", "B22_ES1140_A",
> "B22_ES1140_A", "B22_ES1140_B", "B22_ES1140_B", "B22_ES1141_A",
> "B22_ES1141_A", "B22_ES1141_A", "B22_ES1141_A", "B22_ES1141_B",
> "B22_ES1141_B", "B22_ES1142_A", "B22_ES1142_A", "B22_ES1142_B",
> "B22_ES1142_B", "B22_ES1142_C", "B22_ES1142_C", "B22_ES1142_C",
> "B22_ES1144_A", "B22_ES1189_A", "B25_b001", "B29_ES011_A", "B29_ES063_A",
> "B29_ES063_A", "B29_ES077_A", "B3_ES1002_A", "B3_ES1002_A", "B3_ES1003_A",
> "B3_ES1003_A", "B3_ES1004_A", "B3_ES1004_A", "B3_ES1006_A", "B3_ES1006_A",
> "B3_ES1008_A", "B3_ES1008_A", "B3_ES1009_A", "B3_ES1010_A", "B3_ES1010_A",
> "B3_ES1012_A", "B3_ES1012_A", "B3_ES1012_A", "B3_ES1012_A", "B3_ES1012_A",
> "B3_ES1012_A", "B3_ES1013_A", "B3_ES1013_A", "B3_ES1014_A", "B3_ES1014_A",
> "B3_ES1014_B", "B3_ES1015_A", "B3_ES1015_A", "B3_ES1016_A", "B3_ES1016_A",
> "B3_ES1018_A", "B3_ES1018_A", "B3_ES1018_A", "B3_ES1018_A", "B3_ES1019_A",
> "B3_ES1019_A", "B3_ES1020_A", "B3_ES1021_A", "B3_ES1021_A", "B3_ES1022_A",
> "B3_ES1022_A", "B3_ES1023_A", "B3_ES1023_A", "B3_ES1024_A", "B3_ES1024_A",
> "B3_ES1024_A", "B3_ES1024_A", "B3_ES1025_A", "B3_ES1026_A", "B3_ES1026_A",
> "B3_ES1026_A", "B3_ES1027_A", "B3_ES1027_A", "B3_ES1027_B", "B3_ES1027_B",
> "B3_ES1043_A", "B30_ES059_A", "B31_ES005_A", "B31_ES005_A", "B31_ES007_A",
> "B31_ES008_A", "B31_ES008_A", "B31_ES009_A", "B31_ES009_A", "B31_ES009_B",
> "B31_ES009_B", "B31_ES020_A", "B31_ES020_A", "B31_ES020_B", "B31_ES020_B",
> "B33_b1_ES002_A", "B33_b1_ES002_A", "B33_b1_ES002_B", "B33_b1_ES002_B",
> "B33_b1_ES003_A", "B33_b1_ES003_A", "B33_b1_ES004_A", "B33_b1_ES004_A",
> "B33_b1_ES004_B", "B33_b1_ES004_B", "B33_b1_ES005_A", "B33_b1_ES005_A",
> "B33_b1_ES005_B", "B33_b1_ES005_B", "B33_b2_ES006_A", "B33_b2_ES006_A",
> "B33_b2_ES006_B", "B33_b2_ES006_B", "B33_b2_ES007_A", "B33_b2_ES007_A",
> "B33_b2_ES007_B", "B33_b2_ES007_B", "B33_b2_ES007_C", "B33_b2_ES007_C",
> "B33_b2_ES008_A", "B33_b2_ES008_A", "B33_b2_ES008_A", "B33_b2_ES008_A",
> "B33_b3_ES001_A", "B33_b3_ES001_A", "B33_b4_ES001_A", "B33_b4_ES001_A",
> "B33_b5_ES001_A", "B33_b5_ES001_A", "B33_b6_ES001_A", "B33_b6_ES001_A",
> "B33_b6_ES003_A", "B33_b6_ES003_A", "B33_b6_ES004_A", "B33_b6_ES005_A",
> "B33_b6_ES005_A", "B33_b6_ES006_A", "B33_b6_ES006_A", "B34_b1_ES002_A",
> "B34_b10_ES001_A", "B34_b10_ES001_A", "B34_b10_ES002_A", "B34_b10_ES002_A",
> "B34_b10_ES003_A", "B34_b10_ES004_A", "B34_b10_ES004_A", "B34_b10_ES005_A",
> "B34_b10_ES005_A", "B34_b12_ES001_A", "B34_b12_ES001_A", "B34_b12_ES002_A",
> "B34_b12_ES002_A", "B34_b12_ES003_A", "B34_b12_ES003_A", "B34_b12_ES003_A",
> "B34_b2_ES001_A", "B34_b3_ES001_A", "B34_b3_ES001_A", "B34_b3_ES002_A",
> "B34_b3_ES002_A", "B34_b3_ES003_A", "B34_b3_ES003_A", "B34_b3_ES004_A",
> "B34_b3_ES004_A", "B34_b3_ES005_A", "B34_b3_ES005_A", "B34_b3_ES005_B",
> "B34_b5_ES001_A", "B34_b5_ES001_A", "B34_b5_ES002_A", "B34_b5_ES002_A",
> "B34_b5_ES003_A", "B34_b5_ES003_A", "B34_b5_ES004_A", "B34_b5_ES004_A",
> "B34_b5_ES005_A", "B34_b5_ES005_A", "B34_b5_ES005_B", "B34_b5_ES005_B",
> "B34_b7_ES001_A", "B34_b7_ES001_A", "B34_b7_ES002_A", "B34_b7_ES002_A",
> "B34_b7_ES002_A", "B34_b7_ES003_A", "B34_b7_ES003_A", "B34_b8_ES001_A",
> "B34_b8_ES001_A", "B4_ES1058_A", "B4_ES1058_A", "ES11_A", "ES17_A",
> "RT1ES1_A", "RT1ES1_A", "RT1ES12_A", "RT1ES12_A", "RT1ES2_A",
> "RT1ES3_A", "RT1ES4_A", "RT1ES5_A", "RT1ES5_A", "RT1ES6_A", "RT1ES7_A",
> "RT1ES7_B", "RT1ES7_B", "RT1ES7_B", "RT1ES8_B", "RT1ES8_B", "RT1ES8_B",
> "RT1ES9_A", "RT1ES9_A", "RT2ES1_A", "RT2ES1_A", "RT2ES1_A", "RT2ES11_A",
> "RT2ES11_A", "RT2ES13_A", "RT2ES13_A", "RT2ES13_A", "RT2ES15_A",
> "RT2ES15_A", "RT2ES16_A", "RT2ES2_A", "RT2ES4_A", "RT2ES4_A",
> "RT2ES6_A", "RT2ES6_A", "RT2ES7_A", "RT2ES8_A", "RT2ES9_A"),
> host.length = c(27.1, 27.1, 24.5, 24.5, 28, 28, 31.5, 31.5,
> 29.2, 29.2, 31.9, 31.9, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 26.5, 26.5,
> 26.5, 29.4, 29.4, 29.4, 29.4, 29.4, 29.4, 26.7, 26.7, 26.6,
> 26.6, 26.6, 24.5, 24.5, 28.9, 28.9, 31.2, 31.2, 26, 26.9,
> 26.9, 26.9, 26.9, 26.9, 26.9, 27.9, 26.9, 29.2, 28.5, 28.5,
> 26.5, 26.5, 29.1, 29.1, 27.3, 27.3, 27.3, 27.3, 31.2, 31.2,
> 19.1, 19.1, 28.5, 28.5, 31.6, 31.6, 23, 23, 33.2, 33.2, 30.7,
> 30.7, 30.7, 27.9, 27.9, 27.9, 27.9, 27.9, 27.9, 28.8, 28.8,
> 28.8, 33.2, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.2, 22.2, 22.2, 22.2, 22.2,
> 22.2, 22.2, 17.7, 17.7, 22.2, 21.9, 21.9, 30.5, 30.5, 22.9,
> 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 27.1, 27.1, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5,
> 27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 28.5, 28.1, 28.1, 28.1, 28.1,
> 28.1, 28.1, 28.1, 19.6, 17.4, 34.6, 16.1, 25.4, 25.4, 16.9,
> 27.5, 27.5, 24.6, 24.6, 30.9, 30.9, 26.2, 26.2, 28, 28, 26.8,
> 34, 34, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 30.8, 30.8, 30.7,
> 30.7, 30.7, 33.4, 33.4, 32.1, 32.1, 27.2, 27.2, 27.2, 27.2,
> 27.3, 27.3, 21.4, 22.9, 22.9, 26.7, 26.7, 24, 24, 26.2, 26.2,
> 26.2, 26.2, 19.4, 22.1, 22.1, 22.1, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8,
> 23.2, 18.4, 27.4, 27.4, 25.3, 27.9, 27.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9,
> 22.9, 29.1, 29.1, 29.1, 29.1, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 45.4,
> 45.4, 32.3, 32.3, 32.3, 32.3, 43.6, 43.6, 43.6, 43.6, 41.4,
> 41.4, 41.4, 41.4, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 47.1,
> 47.1, 47.1, 47.1, 49.1, 49.1, 31.6, 31.6, 32.9, 32.9, 30.7,
> 30.7, 30.2, 30.2, 30.8, 32.8, 32.8, 35.8, 35.8, 37.7, 41.4,
> 41.4, 38.7, 38.7, 34.8, 35.6, 35.6, 39.8, 39.8, 42.4, 42.4,
> 32, 32, 35.8, 35.8, 35.8, 33.3, 32.2, 32.2, 30.5, 30.5, 31.9,
> 31.9, 37.8, 37.8, 39.9, 39.9, 39.9, 41.1, 41.1, 45.2, 45.2,
> 41.3, 41.3, 46, 46, 44.1, 44.1, 44.1, 44.1, 38.7, 38.7, 39.2,
> 39.2, 39.2, 50.7, 50.7, 30.2, 30.2, 22, 22, 24, 25, 31, 31,
> 27, 27, 30, 30, 32, 30, 30, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 26, 26, 26,
> 28, 28, 34, 34, 34, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 25, 25, 27, 32, 29,
> 29, 34, 34, 29, 26, 31), host.sex = c("f", "f", "f", "f",
> "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f",
> "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m",
> "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m",
> "m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m",
> "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m",
> "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f", "f",
> "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m",
> "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f",
> "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m",
> "f", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f", "m", "m", "f",
> "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m",
> "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m",
> "m", "m", "m", "m"), position.simplified = c("dorsal", "dorsal",
> "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "anterior", "anterior", "pectoral",
> "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "pelvic", "pelvic", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "genital", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "pectoral", "pectoral", "anterior", "anterior", "pectoral",
> "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pelvic", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "anterior", "anterior", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "anterior", "anterior", "anterior", "anterior", "anterior",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pelvic",
> "pelvic", "pelvic", "pelvic", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pelvic",
> "pelvic", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "anterior", "pelvic",
> "pelvic", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "anterior", "anterior", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "anterior", "pectoral",
> "pelvic", "pelvic", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "anterior",
> "anterior", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "other", "other", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "pelvic", "pelvic", "anterior", "anterior", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "pelvic", "pelvic", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral",
> "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pelvic", "pelvic", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "pectoral", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "pectoral", "dorsal", "other", "pectoral", "pectoral",
> "other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "pectoral", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "dorsal", "dorsal", "dorsal",
> "dorsal", "dorsal", "pectoral", "dorsal", "other"), number.of.parasites.on.host = c(2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 6,
> 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 9, 9,
> 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
> 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4,
> 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4,
> 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
> 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4,
> 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 5,
> 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2,
> 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2), tot.clusters = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 2, 1), of.thorax = c(6.26, 8.51, 6.5, 7.78, 4.26, 5.21,
> 8.37, 7.31, 10.23, 9.14, 7.49, 8.54, 5.43, 6.77, 3.75, 4.56,
> 7.53, 6.96, 9.43, 8.01, 6.47, 4.94, 5.39, 2.75, 2.25, 8.6,
> 7.22, 8.02, 8.13, 7.59, 6.07, 6.04, 7.06, 6.79, 8.64, 7.74,
> 3.71, 6.05, 6.11, 1.25, 1.5, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 4.59, 8.88, 6.94,
> 7.75, 6.32, 6.83, 8.46, 6.81, 6.21, 6.77, 6.54, 8.88, 8.63,
> 8.65, 2.75, 2.25, 10.64, 9.9, 7.94, 6.65, 3, 0.7, 9.98, 7.46,
> 6.77, 6.45, 1.2, 6.9, 7.28, 7.19, 7.23, 6.11, 2.65, 7.9,
> 6.57, 3.72, 4.84, 4.71, 3.5, 1.25, 4.5, 2.15, 2, 1, 1, 0.75,
> 0.66, 2, 2, 3.54, 6.18, 4.61, 8.19, 9.31, 7.14, 7.25, 5.41,
> 4.52, 3.26, 3.54, 7, 6.35, 3.02, 4.87, 6.31, 7.11, 6.45,
> 5.41, 6.39, 1.3, 0.9, 6.53, 5.53, 6.57, 5.88, 1.6, 2, 1.5,
> 3.1, 1.75, 5, 0.75, 5.69, 6.06, 1.2, 4.81, 4.38, 3.9, 3.7,
> 9.22, 9.94, 8.2, 6.9, 6.89, 5.97, 2.3, 6.82, 8.26, 2.75,
> 1.1, 0.3, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 8.69, 8.15, 7.57, 8.87, 4.99, 8.71,
> 9.21, 7.34, 9.03, 4.6, 4, 2, 2.25, 7.06, 7.55, 3, 6.48, 6.5,
> 2.95, 1.57, 6.47, 5.55, 9.84, 7.41, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 5.71, 5.75,
> 5.17, 2.2, 3.2, 1, 0.5, 4, 1.25, 6.91, 7.86, 5.34, 6.04,
> 7.2, 5.72, 5.61, 4.47, 8.81, 9.11, 7.35, 6.71, 5.87, 7.12,
> 8.27, 8.1, 6.65, 6.18, 7.74, 9.87, 7.98, 8.96, 9.33, 8.88,
> 8.14, 9.12, 7.67, 8.09, 7.76, 10.85, 9.65, 8.17, 5.69, 6.98,
> 9.12, 11.8, 10.69, 10.4, 9.56, 8.43, 9.73, 9.15, 11.83, 5.76,
> 4.78, 6.87, 7.32, 7.55, 7.75, 12.11, 8.51, 8.67, 7.2, 6.68,
> 10.27, 10.28, 5.68, 10.91, 7.84, 12.31, 10.73, 6.06, 7.14,
> 7.23, 10.1, 7.04, 10.79, 11.2, 5.62, 7.07, 8.82, 9.93, 8.68,
> 5.19, 7.06, 5.15, 5.83, 6.09, 7.47, 5.82, 10.28, 12.13, 7.15,
> 7.06, 9.44, 9.13, 12.74, 10.78, 11.23, 11.65, 9.56, 10.25,
> 10.94, 12.05, 9.32, 8.22, 7.97, 8.73, 11.77, 11.03, 6.77,
> 7.95, 11.03, 9, 9.5, 7.84, 6.29, 3.67, 4.1, 4.1, 4.8, 7.5,
> 3, 4.4, 4.7, 4.1, 5.8, 3.8, 3.8, 4.6, 4.5, 2.7, 3.3, 3.5,
> 2.6, 3.4, 5.1, 4.3, 6, 2.9, 4, 4.3, 4, 4.6, 4.7, 6, 7.7,
> 5, 8.7, 6.6, 4.3, 3.9, 4.6, 5.4, 7.4, 5.7, 4.2, 2.7), parasite.eggs = c("yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no",
> "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no",
> "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no",
> "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no",
> "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no",
> "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no",
> "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no",
> "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes",
> "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes",
> "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no",
> "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no",
> "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes",
> "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes",
> "yes", "yes", "no"), number.simp = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,
> 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 2,
> 1, 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1.5,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1, 1,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,
> 1.5, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,
> 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5,
> 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,
> 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
> 2, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5)), row.names = c(NA,
> -332L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Not an answer: I think you should write everything in one command. It improves readability. I think saving `a` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks (and thanks for editing?)! I'm new to ggplot2 so I'm still wrapping my head around the different structure :)

Comment: @Lstat yes I have added to the best of my abilities!

Comment: @Lstat there you go, thanks again.

Comment: I have overlooked the dput link at the top of your question. Sorry. You can remove it from the question...

Comment: Thanks for sharing a reproducible example, that makes it much easier to help you. I would suggest, next time, sharing a **minimal** reproducible example. That's a lot of data you shared, but probably 10 or 20 rows would have been plenty. Try `dput(data[1:10, ])` next time---it will make your question more approachable and probably speed up how quickly you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
ggplot(originalRfiltered3, aes(x = host.length, y = of.thorax) ) + 
 geom_point(aes(size = number.simp, fill = host.sex), shape=21, colour="black" ) + 
 scale_fill_manual(name = "Host Sex", labels=c("F", "M"), values = c("red", "blue") ) + 
     scale_size_continuous(name = "Group Size", labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4+") ) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "black", formula = y~poly(x,2)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x = "Host length (cm)" ) +
  labs(y = "Parasite length (mm)" ) +
  labs(title = "Correlation between size of host and parasite")  +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=8)))
```

Black circles are defined in `shape=21`, colour is defined in the `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks you very much. one last question: is it possible to increase the size of the dots next to M and F in the legend? its nit-picky but I was unable to find the code for that too... @Lstat

Comment: Since it's not called out, worth mentioning to OP @Lstat: This answer makes a good change to not use `data$column` inside `aes()`, just use bare column names. On simple plots `data$column` will work, but it will break if you use, e.g., facets or `stat_*` functions that do aggregation.